# iphone core data app crash

Tags: iphone, core-data, crash

I'm able to complete my iphone app using core data internally.
But for the first time when I'm running in simulator or on device its crashing with following error:

2010-03-18 10:55:41.785 CrData[1605:4603] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 UserInfo=0x50448d0 "Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)", {
    NSUnderlyingException = Error validating url for store;
}

When I run the app again in simulator or on device, its running perfectly. I'm not able to identify the exact problem. Can some one guide me on how to proceed further???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unroll the errors and see what is going on.  Inside of that error (which you can set a break point on objc_exception_thrown to catch it) is the userInfo dictionary which you can interrogate to see what the underlying errors are.

### update

What does your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` creation code look like?

Did you add a break point and do a `po [error userInfo]` so see if there were any additional errors in the userInfo?

Core Data can and does send you a hierarchy of errors and frequently on a small amount of information is exposed at the top error.  Unrolling the errors via the debugger is best to determine the underlying causes.

### update

> Code error 513 means, write permissions for creating store in core data app failed. But the same piece of code is running well from next time. So, what might be the actual problem is not known to me..... how to proceed here.

Again, what does your persistent store creation code look like?  You need to post some code so that I can take a look at it.  Otherwise I am just guessing which is no fun.

Comment: Code error 513 means, write permissions for creating store in core data app failed. But the same piece of code is running well from next time. So, what might be the actual problem is not known to me..... how to proceed here.

Comment: Excellent.  I was having the same problem with inserting into a DB in the 'bundle' path, so I was told to copy the file into the 'user' library space.  When I did that, I decided to 'move' (i.e., to save memory) -- however, move needs permission to delete -- duh!  When I dumped [error UserInfo] that became more apparent to me.  Now my copy works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

8.2 has become more strict on the location (and permissions) of your persistent store. I've just seen the "513" error appear when the database was stored in the bundle and used with a read only option. Using a device with 8.1 it worked without failing, but on 8.2 the error and exception appeared causing a crash. On the simulator the exception did not occur and happily continued to work.

The solution that worked to copy the database into the application documents directory at start up.

NSFileManager copyItemAtURL:toURL:error will come in useful.